# Rearrange order of sections in r markdown pdf based on score

Tags: r, pdf, r-markdown

I have two data frames like these full of info about candidates for a job:

```
Scores<-structure(list(Name = c("John Smith", "Jane Doe", 
"John Doe", "Jan Jenkins", "Lauren John", "Jennifer Patty", 
"Zachary Gala"), `Applicant Name` = c(1, 18, 5, 6, 3, 4, 2), 
    `Sum-100` = c(75, 85, 97, 53, 61, 31, 85), `Edu.-20` = c(12, 
    19, 20, 10, 14, 8, 18), `Personality-15` = c(10, 14, 15, 
    8, 8, 7, 12), `Verbal-15` = c(12, 12, 14, 7, 6, 6, 13), `Maturity-15` = c(14, 
    11, 15, 8, 8, 5, 13), `Research-15` = c(13, 10, 14, 10, 13, 
    4, 14), `Intellect-15` = c(16, 19, 19, 10, 11, 1, 15), `LOR-10` = c(NaN, 
    9, 3, 8, 6, 4, NaN), `PS-10` = c(NaN, 8, 3, 8, 5, 4, NaN)), row.names = c(NA, 
-7L), groups = structure(list(Name = c("John Smith", "Jane Doe", 
"John Doe", "Jan Jenkins", "Jennifer Patty", "Jennifer Patty", 
"Zachary Gala"), .rows = structure(list(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
    7L), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", "vctrs_vctr", 
"list"))), row.names = c(NA, 7L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))

Comments<-structure(list(`Applicant Name` = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 3, 3, 
4, 5, 6, 3, 3, 1, 1, 18), Name = c("John Smith", "John Smith", 
"Zachary Gala", "Zachary Gala", "Lauren John", "Zachary Gala", 
"Zachary Gala", "Lauren John", "Lauren John", 
"Jennifer Patty", "John Doe", "Jan Jenkins", "Lauren John", 
"Lauren John", "John Smith", "John Smith", 
"Jane Doe"), Overall = c("overall good  and bla bla bla this is a very long comment because I want to see how it works etc. etc. bla", 
"cant do it", "breathtaking", "fdwdf wfew", "joke was funny", 
"Interesting person", "asdfd asdasf dasjlfoeiwna osdnkdasjbfiabdk hfhajh dsfklhdsakl hfawei uhdk jashfiaw ulhfk jldbkla hbvliub", 
"Dumb", "sfdgsv", "do not take this person", "incredible opportunity for us", 
"medium plus", "bla", "goao", "dfg", "ffohfosfdosfdifof", "Silly"
)), row.names = c(NA, -17L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

And I'm compiling all this data and showing graphs and tables about it in a pdf that I'll probably be printing and physically handing to a bunch of people that will be reviewing the candidates.  There is a section about each candidate that looks like this:

[image]

And I just had one of the people who is a reviewer ask me if I could reorganize the document so that applicants with higher scores would have their sections near the top of the document.  Is there a way to do that with code?  Worth mentioning I don't actually have their scores and data yet (will come from a redcap database at the last second), so Ideally the second I get the raw data, I could code it to automatically move everything around.  To physically reorganize where their section is in the pdf.   I can imagine some sort of filter in this code:

```
kable(School%>%filter(applicant_name=="2")%>%select(-applicant_name))%>%
  kable_paper("hover", full_width = F)
```

That would filter to the person with the "second best" score or something, but how could I reorganize what photo of what applicant went where? And what name went in the section header? Is it even possible?

Comment: Could you just rewrite your code to generate individual PDF files per application and then dump them into a list (maybe by name or code). You can then use any attribute to associated with that code to assemble the individual PDF pages into a single document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could first arrange the tibble by the score of interest, then generate dynamic sections using `\section{}` (LaTeX) in a loop.

Something along these lines would accomplish it, assuming `kableExtra`-tables is handled the same way as `knitr::kable`

````
---
output: pdf_document
---


```{r, results='asis', echo=FALSE, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE}
library(dplyr)
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)

Scores<-structure(list(Name = c("John Smith", "Jane Doe", 
"John Doe", "Jan Jenkins", "Lauren John", "Jennifer Patty", 
"Zachary Gala"), `Applicant Name` = c(1, 18, 5, 6, 3, 4, 2), 
    `Sum-100` = c(75, 85, 97, 53, 61, 31, 85), `Edu.-20` = c(12, 
    19, 20, 10, 14, 8, 18), `Personality-15` = c(10, 14, 15, 
    8, 8, 7, 12), `Verbal-15` = c(12, 12, 14, 7, 6, 6, 13), `Maturity-15` = c(14, 
    11, 15, 8, 8, 5, 13), `Research-15` = c(13, 10, 14, 10, 13, 
    4, 14), `Intellect-15` = c(16, 19, 19, 10, 11, 1, 15), `LOR-10` = c(NaN, 
    9, 3, 8, 6, 4, NaN), `PS-10` = c(NaN, 8, 3, 8, 5, 4, NaN)), row.names = c(NA, 
-7L), groups = structure(list(Name = c("John Smith", "Jane Doe", 
"John Doe", "Jan Jenkins", "Jennifer Patty", "Jennifer Patty", 
"Zachary Gala"), .rows = structure(list(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
    7L), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", "vctrs_vctr", 
"list"))), row.names = c(NA, 7L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

```{r, results='asis', echo=FALSE}
#Arrange tibble by the Sum-100 column in descending order.
arrangedScores <- Scores %>% 
  arrange(desc(`Sum-100`))

#Extract the names in descending order to iterate through in the for loop
arrangedNames <- arrangedScores$Name

#Uncomment to include images
#arrangedScores$img <- "example_image.png"

for(i in arrangedNames){
  tableFrame <- arrangedScores %>% 
    dplyr::filter(Name == i)
  
  #Create section header with name and score
  cat(paste0("\\section{",i, ". Score: ",tableFrame$`Sum-100` ),"}")
  
  #Uncomment to include images
  #cat("![](",tableFrame$img,")")
  
  #Print table. Need print() to print kable in loop, ref
  #https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/kable.html#generate-multiple-tables-from-a-for-loop
  print(kable(tableFrame))
  
  #Remove this to not generate new page for each application
  cat("\\newpage")
  
}
```
````